# How to invoke Action while clicking button inside the jquery dialog?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, jquery-dialog

I have created jQuery ui dialog using the below code. it worked fine. but, close button  is not working. I added "Add Trade" button in the dialog, when I click the button I want to invoke an Controller Action to the add trade at the same time the dialog should not disappear and it should show the same content. do you have any suggestions for this problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
     $('#divtrade').dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         width: 1400,
         height: 600,
         resizable: false,
         title: 'New Trades',
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
             "Close": function () {
                 //close button not working
                 $('#divtrade').dialog("close");
             },
             "Add Trade": function () {
                   //how to invoke controller to add trade using jquery, at the same time
                   //dialog should not disappear, it should show the previous view
             }
         }
     });
 });


$('.newtrade').click(function () {
    $('#divtrade').load('@Url.Action("NewTrade","Trade")').dialog('open');

});
   </script>

  <div id="divtrade"  style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: So, you just want to do an ajax request inside the "add trade" callback, right? If so look into $.ajax() in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this this :

```
$.ajax(
   url:'@Url.Action("YourAction","YourController")',
   success : function(data){
      $('#divtrade').html(data);
      $('#divtrade').show();
      // You may consider to close the dialog after loading the content
      $('#divtrade').dialog("close");
   }
);
```

If you want full details about [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)